# How to get a unique serial_number for a abstract base class in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, unique, abstract

I have a abstract base model and two child models:

```py
class Component(models.Model):

    serial = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ChildComponentA(Component):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

class ChildComponentB(Component):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want the `serial` field to be unique for all children but this does not work for me.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is impossible to do that with a *abstract* model. With a non-abstract one there is also a table `Component`, and the primary key is thus guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `PositiveIntegerField` by `AutoField` ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#autofield)) or you can use another type of unique field, like an UUIDField, if another format is possible for you.

Comment: Changing the PositiveIntegerField for an AutoField results in `AssertionError: Model app.ChildComponentA can't have more than one auto-generated field.`
I guess that every child has its own primary_key id which colides with the AutoField from the abstract model.